# Windsor Fluent Interface Lifestyle

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, fluent-interface

Are these equivalent syntaxes for setting component lifestyle?

```
Component.For<IFoo>()
         .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
         .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)

Component.For<IBar>()
         .ImplementedBy<Bar>()
         .LifeStyle.Transient
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are.

Until there's a complete documentation on the fluent interface, the best source for information is [the tests](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/InversionOfControl/Castle.MicroKernel.Tests/Registration/).

Another source of information is this [wiki page](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API).